# Reindexing a index in elasticsearch - ELK

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, logstash, kibana

What's the best practise to reindex an elastic search index? [This](http://www.mooreds.com/wordpress/archives/2115) post has few steps which involves stopping logstash indexer before reindexing an index but that's not an option for me as its a production server.

I had a problem where there were no *.raw fields in an index, because of missing default mapping template. I used the mapping template from Elasticsearch found [here](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-elasticsearch/blob/b85e72e8c160100a84a6ebc341fda88f58de0999/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-template.json) and configured my ES cluster to use it, but I guess it will only be used when either a new index is created or when I explicitly reindex an existing index.

Also `/_template?pretty` resulted back an empty response, but after adding the aforementioned template `/_template?pretty` reveals a new template, but will the new index that would be created use this new template automatically? Or do I need to configure ES explicitly asking it to use them?

I would really appreciate some help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this IMO is to have an alias pointing to your actual index. (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html), something like `my-index-alias` pointing to `my-actual-index-20170101`

```
POST /_aliases
{
    "actions" : [
        { "add" : { "index" : "my-actual-index-20170101", "alias" : "my-index-alias" } }
    ]
}
```

When you query (or add stuffs) to your index, you always use the alias name.

If you need to reindex, you reindex to another index ( `my-actual-index-20170127` by example) and when the reindexing is done, you update the alias to point to the new index.

```
POST /_aliases
{
    "actions" : [
        { "remove" : { "index" : "my-actual-index-20170101", "alias" : "my-index-alias" } },
        { "add" : { "index" : "my-actual-index-20170127", "alias" : "my-index-alias" } }
    ]
}
```

It'll allow you to reindex an index without changing any code / having any downtime.

Now, regarding the actual reindexing problem-- I've been using the `elasticsearch-reindex` node app with a lot of success ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticsearch-reindex).

Its usage is easy :

after installing it with npm ( `npm install -g elasticsearch-reindex`), you can just run

```
elasticsearch-reindex -f http://localhost:9200/my-actual-index-20170101/{type of documents} -t http://localhost:9200/my-actual-index-20170127
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to reindex your documents(using Kibana Sense) in another index with the new template applied can be:

```
POST /_reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "source-index"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "dest-index"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do a lot of different actions with Elasticsearch including re-indexing is [Curator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/5.4/reindex.html).

Its latest [version](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/5.4/version-compatibility.html) is compatible with ES 5.x and 6.x